Where should i add (android:exported="true")
I am currently editing an old application to support android 14 the only thing that im stuck on is adding the (android:exported="true") to the androidmanifest.xml and i dont know where to add the code.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.sp.protector.helper">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <receiver android:name="ProtectorHelperReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_RESTARTED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
                <data android:scheme="package"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="HelperWakeupReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.sp.protector.action.WAKEUP_HELPER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>

i tried:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.sp.protector.helper">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <receiver android:name="ProtectorHelperReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_RESTARTED"/>
                <action android:exported="true"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
                <data android:scheme="package"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="HelperWakeupReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.sp.protector.action.WAKEUP_HELPER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>

but i got this error :
brut.androlib.exceptions.AndrolibException: brut.common.BrutException: could not exec (exit code = 1): [C:\Users\Manij\AppData\Local\Temp\brut_util_Jar_69206966786179757076419828386311953032.tmp, link, -o, C:\Users\Manij\AppData\Local\Temp\APKTOOL1611484024447185108.tmp, --package-id, 127, --min-sdk-version, 31, --target-sdk-version, 33, --version-code, 3, --version-name, 2.0, --no-auto-version, --no-version-vectors, --no-version-transitions, --no-resource-deduping, --allow-reserved-package-id, --no-compile-sdk-metadata, --warn-manifest-validation, -e, C:\Users\Manij\AppData\Local\Temp\APKTOOL4006206227314927488.tmp, -0, arsc, -I, C:\Users\Manij\AppData\Local\apk-editor-studio\frameworks\1.apk, --manifest, C:\Users\Manij\AppData\Local\Temp\apk-editor-studio\apk\{14b6c1a8-808c-433c-bc1f-32f964756b55}\AndroidManifest.xml, C:\Users\Manij\AppData\Local\Temp\apk-editor-studio\apk\{14b6c1a8-808c-433c-bc1f-32f964756b55}\build\resources.zip]


I know you are new on StackOverflow, but "where to use android:exported="true"" is not the difficult thing and should not be asked. A simple Google search can help you. Be careful while asking simple questions here, otherwise someone will downvote your question.

From Android 12 (API level 31) and above, you need to set the android:exported attribute in your AndroidManifest.xml. updated your manifest to
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.sp.protector.helper">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <receiver android:name="ProtectorHelperReceiver" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_RESTARTED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
                <data android:scheme="package"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="HelperWakeupReceiver" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.sp.protector.action.WAKEUP_HELPER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>

You could read more here
